How to really detect optical rectification?
I am studying the non-linear optics. And there is a topic about optical rectification. So the mechanism is basically to let light pass through a $\chi^{2}$ medium. The optical rectification is to transfer the incident light to the DC polarization in the medium.
So I got the idea from Introduction to Nonlinear Optics by Geoffrey New. If I put two capacitor plates on the top and at the bottom of the nonlinear crystal and feed the light from the lateral direction of the crystal and connect a resistor across the capacitor plates.

(I adapt this picture from Introduction to Nonlinear Optics by Geoffrey New)
Can I get DC current? and can I measure out the optical rectification by the current through the resistor?
